# SwiftUI Making an Alarm

Tags: swift, swiftui

How can I schedule an alarm to play using SwiftUI (like the alarms in the Apple clock app) for more than 30 seconds?

The only way that I have seen so far is to schedule a notification and add a custom sound which will only play up to 30 seconds.

Comment: Welcome to SO - Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve, edit and format your questions.